# Boat Airdopes - Mic - Not Recognized - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, microphone

I have Ubuntu 20.04.

So far I have been using Sony's bluetooth headset, and it worked very well.

Recently I bought Boat Airdopes. With this, Ubuntu recognizes only the speakers, but when it comes to Mic it is not recognizing its presence at all. Please take a look at the screenshot of the Sound Settings. The output is recognized properly, but the input Mic is not recognized. Could you please help in sorting out this issue?

[Screenshot of Sound Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPxOM.png)

Thanks
Srikanth

Comment: I recently purchased Airpodes 141, I'm also facing the same issue. Speakers are recognized but mic is not recognized.